# How to start to offer BTC --> PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Well, I am not a website owner, but I can convert BTC to Paypal..

So how should i offer the service to anybody? the platform has gotton so wide that it feels dumb to create a website, and i dont wanna pay exchange site commission.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go through alot to get nearly enough rep for people to trade with you.

Here are a few tips you could do to get you off your feet.

1. Try offering trades especially in small amounts.
2. Don't be afraid to go first. If someone scams you, you can charge back.
3. If you have any reputable friends that trust you, you could get them to vouch for you. However do **NOT** try and buy a vouch.
4. Try trading with different payment methods, especially irreversible ones. That takes away alot of the risk people see in you.
5. Link an account on another site that you have a reputation on. Preferably one that has strict rules against account selling.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a BTC dollars in pay pal, it's a bit complicated, you need your PayPal address, you select the maximum amount of bitcoin is 0.25 in Coin2Pal and then will receive approximately $ 100 according to the value of bitcoin, but now get the quarter to a bitcoin that costs $ 500 will be more than 100 dollars, the bad is q charge as 0.3 0.25 bitcoin your happen to your account. If a person gives you bitcoin you should access this form of payment, but if you want money without conversions you can ask to be paid in dollars on paypal

Comment: This answer is hard to understand, because it doesn't present the thought process clearly. I suggest adding more punctuation, and reading it out loud to yourself to see where it might be hard to follow. I'm also not sure whether the answerer understood what the asker wants to do.